# MongoDB Schema Design with same type data types

Tags: mongodb

I am designing a MongoDB collection and ran into a design question.

The collection holds distances between two points. It currently is setup like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7dbc6f16eac41778ae8255"),
    "start" : 122,
    "end" : 156,
    "routes" : [ 
        {
            "routeType" : 1,
            "Distance" : 455.0
        }, 
        {
            "routeType" : 4,
            "Distance" : 455.0
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I can search for start and end values. The issue is that "start" could be 156 and "end" 122. The user could search for either combination.

Is there a better design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about design like this

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7dbc6f16eac41778ae8255"),
        "places" : [ 
            122, 
            156
        ],
        "routes" : [ 
            {
                "routeType" : 1.0,
                "Distance" : 455.0
            }, 
            {
                "routeType" : 4.0,
                "Distance" : 455.0
            }
        ]
    }
```

You don't care what is starting point, and what is end point. Just wrap them in `places` and make sure your `places` have 2 points. When searching

```
    db.getCollection('yourtable').find({places: 122, places: 156})
```

And

```
    db.getCollection('yourtable').find({places: 156, places: 122})
```

They both give you the same result you want

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.